# Convert string date to date in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, date, pyspark, databricks

I have a column in a dataframe that has string date like this :

```
 date
'Apr 7 2022 12:00AM'
'Apr 17 2022 12:00AM'
```

I want to convert it to date column and expect this:

```
date
2022-04-07
2022-04-17
```

I used this code :

```
df = df.withColumn("date",to_date(F.to_timestamp(df.date,'MMM dd yyyy')))
```

But it's giving me this error:

> Caused by: DateTimeParseException: Text 'Apr 7 2022 12:00AM' could not be parsed at index 4

Anybody has experience with this. Any help would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved using this :

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
df = df.withColumn("date",to_date(func.to_timestamp(df.date,'MMM d yyyy hh:mma')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the exact parse string. Here is the [reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html).

```
data = [
    ['Apr 7 2022 12:00AM'],
    ['Apr 17 2022 12:00AM']
]
cols = ['date']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)

df.withColumn('date', f.to_date(f.to_timestamp('date', 'MMM d yyyy hh:mma'))) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+----------+
|date      |
+----------+
|2022-04-07|
|2022-04-17|
+----------+
```

Comment: Getting this error on bigger data frame : Caused by: DateTimeParseException: Text 'Apr  3 2020 12:00AM' could not be parsed at index 4

Comment: What version of spark do you use?

Comment: I'm using Spark 3.3.0 Compute Cluster in Databricks. I can change the config quickly if that's the problem. Please suggest